# Same "controller as" name in angular js directive breaks function in parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I've a controller with some items for `ng-repeat` and each item should get a random color so I use `ng-style` with a function in that controller called `randColor(...)`.

```
app.controller('TestController', function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.items = [ { name: 'item 1' } , { name: 'item 2'} ];

    vm.randColor = function (item) {
        if (!item) {
            return 'red';
        }
        else if (!item.color)
        {
            var color = 'rgb('
                + _.random(0, 255) + ','
                + _.random(0, 255) + ','
                + _.random(0, 255) + ')';
            item.color = color;
        }

        return item.color;
    };
});
```

I'm using the "controller as" syntax for this and I usually always use `vm` as the short name of my controllers. I've never had a problem with doing so, even when naming "sub"-controllers the same way.

But now I've tried to do the same thing with a directive and suddenly my `randColor(...)` function stopped working.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9c53CgTckDtGeQL0GdB1?p=preview) of my problem.

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="TestController as vm">
    <!-- This works -->
    <h3>Without Directive (controllerAs: 'vm')</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
        <div ng-style="{ background: vm.randColor(item) }" class="container">
            <h4>{{ item.name }}</h4>
            <div ng-controller="TestDirectiveController as vm">
                <div>{{ vm.title }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- This works -->
    <h3>Test Directive Alternative (controllerAs: 'directiveVM')</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
        <div ng-style="{ background: vm.randColor(item) }" class="container">
            <h4>{{ item.name }}</h4>
            <test-directive-alt></test-directive-alt>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- This DOES NOT work -->
    <h3>Test Directive (controllerAs: 'vm')</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
        <div ng-style="{ background: vm.randColor(item) }" class="container">
            <h4>{{ item.name }}</h4>
            <test-directive></test-directive>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
app.controller('TestDirectiveController', function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.title = 'test';
});

app.directive('testDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            controller: 'TestDirectiveController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true,
            template: '<div>{{ vm.title }}</div>'
        };
    });

app.directive('testDirectiveAlt', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            controller: 'TestDirectiveController',
            controllerAs: 'directiveVM',
            bindToController: true,
            template: '<div>{{ directiveVM.title }}</div>'
        };
    });
```

**Output:**

[image]

I know I could just use a different name for the controller as in my example, but why does this happen in the first place?

And is there a way to get it working with the same name?

Comment: Did you try to define a new `scope`? The problem might be that the directive is using the the same scope as the one where `vm` is defined. For that reason it might not work. You can add a scope to the directive.

Comment: Yikes, you are totally right, by just adding `scope: true` it worked...there goes the last 3 hours of my life. You can formulate it to an answer if you want to get the credit for it! Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you're facing seems to be related to the fact that the directive is being executed on the same scope as the scope where the controller is defined as `vm`.

What you need to do is to create a new scope **`scope: {}`** within the directive.

```
app.directive('testDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {},
            controller: 'TestDirectiveController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true,
            template: '<div>{{ vm.title }}</div>'
        };
    });
```

With that, the `controllerAs` should create a new `vm` attribute in the directive scope.