# AngularJS mixing same name controllers from different modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was working on an AngularJS web application which had quite a few sub-modules. Two of the sub-modules had the CRUD functionality therefore both these modules had a few controllers with the same name. For an idea of how the code looked like, have a look at the snippet below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.6" data-semver="1.5.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script>
    angular
      .module('app', [
        'app.one',
        'app.two'
      ]);

    angular
      .module('app.one', [])
      .controller('MyCtrl', function() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.message = 'Hello World from app.one!';
      });

    angular
      .module('app.two', [])
      .controller('MyCtrl', function() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.message = 'Hello World from app.two!';
      });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
  <h1>{{ vm.message }}</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

You can also find this at plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/JRwJsrJd84nPnjj36GAZ.

Now, the problem is that I'm confused. To me it doesn't make sense for AngularJS to confuse controllers of same names but in different modules. If anyone can explain this and also suggest a way to overcome this, I'd be really appreciate that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If dig deep - all `requires` for modules are loaded one by one, consolidating each `$provide` values in `$injector` or parent module. Angular.js: `function module(name, requires, configFn) { ... }`, `function loadModules(modulesToLoad) { ... }`. From notes `$injector` is bind to element, so if you have `app` and all `$provided` is bind to `app` element, you just overwrote `MyCtrl` when you `$injected` `app.two`. `$inject` and `$provide` works with names as keys, that's why you overwrote it.

Answer (score 1):

You should have unique names for your controllers. In your app.js you do like below

```
angular
    .module('app', [
        'app.one',
        'app.two'
      ]);
```

Angular will load both `app.one` and `app.two` When you have a controller called `MyCtrl` in both of these modules, it is just going to pick up the most recent one. In this case, the controller from `app.two`.

You could overcome this by selectively loading which modules you want based on a condition or else simply have unique controller names!

Comment: This part I figured out, what I can't understand is that lets say, if I try to load a controller from within a module (let's suppose using ui.router)... still it gets the controller in the last loaded module. Doesn't this kind of, kill the purpose of encapsulation? Or am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: @haseebahmed7 - look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804362/same-controller-as-name-in-angular-js-directive-breaks-function-in-parent-cont - setting isolated scope on the directive solved the problem for me.